# Calling specific object from a table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I am trying to show a scoreboard at the end of a quiz of how all users scored on that specific quiz. To do so, I am calling the index and displaying username, category, and score:

```
 <% @participations.each_with_index do |participation, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td>#<%= index + 1 %></td>
      <td><%= participation.user.username %></td>
      <td><%= participation.category %></td>
      <td><%= participation.score %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

By calling the index though, it is showing all scores in the Participation model. For instance, if I have three quiz categories: history, sports, and business, it would show scores for all three of those categories in this table.

To fix this, I believe I need to call a specific object -- in this case, the "history" category column -- to filter the scoreboard table for scores for that quiz. Is that possible by altering the index query?

Side Note: the Participations table looks like this after the migration:

```
  class CreateParticipations < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :participations do |t|
        t.references :user
        t.string :category
        t.boolean :finished, default: false
        t.integer :current_question_index, default: 0
        t.integer :score, default: 0
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Scoreboard Controller:

```
 class ScoreboardController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @participations = Participation.where(finished: true).order(score: :desc)
       end
   end
```

Comment: please update the question with the relavant controller code. And try changing the controller code to `@participations = Participation.where(category: params[:category])` given that you pass the category in the url parameters

Comment: Good catch @Kkulikovskis. Updated op with controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you're calling *all* the values for the `participations` table. You need to filter the query to only return the `category` value you want:

```
 @participations = Participation.where(finished: true, category: "history").order(score: :desc)
```

A good way to do this would be to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :scoreboards do
   get ":category", to: :index, on: :collection #-> url.com/scoreboards/history
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
#app/controllers/scoreboards_controller.rb
class ScoreboardsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       if params[:category]
         @participations = Participation.where(finished: true, category: params[:category]).order(score: :desc)
       else
         @participations = Participation.where(finished: true).order(score: :desc)
       end
   end
end
```

---

A pro-tip here is to use [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for your `categories`:

```
#app/models/participation.rb
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum category: [:history, :sports, :business]
end
```

You'll have to change your table to have an *integer* for `category`:

```
change_column :participations, :category, :integer, default: 0
```

The `enum` will store *integers* for each of the categories you define. If you read the docs, you'll see the extent of its effectiveness (allows you to load various instance methods etc).

Most importantly, it will DRY up your db - allowing you to store numbers for the various categories, making your program more efficient, and ultimately allowing you to extend it more uniformly.

Comment: This worked well for the project and we're correctly filtering for category now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
     class ScoreboardController < ApplicationController
       def index
         if params[:category].present?
           @participations = Participation.where(finished: true, params[:category]).order(score: :desc)
         else
           @participations = Participation.where(finished: true).order(score: :desc)
         end
       end
     end
```

then in url you can have filters like index?category=history